# how to change a character of a string and retrive back

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

i need to convert some string with pre-define values i have stored in an array. for example
i am having an array of string like `string[] arr = {"a=z","p=v","l=t","e=m"}`
now i am getting some string from edittext by:`string val = et.gettext().tostring;`

now what i want is to convert that value from edittext to be replaced by the characters stored in the array, for example if user enters "apple" in the edit text it will convert to"
apple = zvvtm; as i define charecters in array.
and again if i want to show it back then zvvtm will convert to apple;

Comment: it is better to store rules like that in a map instead of a string array

Comment: *"now i am getting some string from edittext by: `string val = et.gettext().tostring;`"* Not in Java you're not.

Comment: USe the entries of the array arr to create 2 maps: Map<Character,Character>. Then, it's easy to iterate a String, obtain the translation for each character and build the translation in a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to get you the replacement. Same way you can try it for reverse.

```
    HashMap map=new HashMap();
    String[] arr = {"a=z","p=v","l=t","e=m"};
    String text="apple";
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        String string = arr[i];
        String replace=string.split("=")[0];
        String replaceWith=string.split("=")[1];
        map.put(replace,replaceWith);
    }
    String newString="";
    char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char c = chars[i];
        if(map.keySet().contains(String.valueOf(c)))
            newString+=map.get(String.valueOf(c));
        else
            newString+=c;
    }

    System.out.println(newString);
```

This code is just to give you idea, this code can be optimized for performance improvement.

Comment: exactly what i want..thanks @java learner it worked....